# German Websites for Literature?

Tags: resource

Are there any German websites for literature, like Goodreads? Or for that matter German book shops like Amazon.

Comment: Goodreads supports multiple languages and German features prominently among them. I keep track of all my books there, regardless of language. There are German book shops, too, of course, starting with amazon.de, buch.de and buecher.de

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for classical (as in older) literature, give the [Gutenberg Project](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page) a try, it has tons of Ebooks with texts in the public domain. You'll find lots of classical German texts from Authors like Goethe and Schiller.